# DOM injection and Knockout timing issues

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, breeze

I am iterating over a collection of observable data, but some of that data gets handed to a javascript function to create a tag cloud. An earlier version of this site using ajax and call backs worked as expected: get data, iterate over collection, inject into target DOM objects and all is right with the world.

Now that I've 'evolved' to using Breeze, and promises, I have a timing issue whereby my tag cloud gets created, but I believe I am injecting it too soon. I have verified that if I hit a breakpoint in my JQuery, and inspect the DOM, those elements are not yet available. 
How do I invoke a javascript method to manipulate the DOM when dealing w/promises?

```
define(['services/datacontext', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/app', 'services/logger', 'services/dataService'],
    function (datacontext, router, system, app, logger, dataService) {
        var member = ko.observable();
        var positions = ko.observableArray();
        var tags = ko.observableArray();


        //#region Internal Methods
        function activate(routeData) {
            logger.log('Summary View Activated called', null, 'summary', true);
            var id = parseInt(routeData.id);
            datacontext.getMemberById(id, member);
            datacontext.getPositions(id, positions).then(populateGraphics);
            initLookups();

        logger.log('Summary View Activate completed', null, 'summary', true);
             return ;
        }


    var initLookups = function () {
            salutations(datacontext.lookups.salutations);
        };


        var populateGraphics = function (pos) {
            logger.log('populateGraphics called', null, 'home', true);

   /// changed code that corrects issue based on suggestions 
        var n = $(".positionTagCloud").length;
        if (n == 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                populateGraphics();
            }, 500);
        }
    // end changes

            for (var j = 0; j < positions().length; j++) {
                var target;
                var fill = d3.scale.category20();

                var cloud = function (wordList, targetName) {
                    target = targetName;
                    d3.layout.cloud().size([540, 200])
                            .words(wordList.map(function (d) { return { text: d.name(), size: d.weight() * 1 }; }))
                            .rotate(function () { return ~ ~(Math.random() * 2) * 11; })
                            .font("Impact")
                            .fontSize(function (d) { return d.size; })
                            .on("end", draw)
                            .start();
                };

                function draw(words) {
                    d3.select(target).append("svg")
                            .attr("width", 540)
                            .attr("height", 200)
                            .attr("id", "canvas")
                            .attr("class", "cloudCanvas")
                            .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(250,100)")
                            .selectAll("text")
                            .data(words)
                            .enter().append("text")
                            .style("font-size", function (d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                            .style("font-family", "Impact")
                            .style("fill", function (d, i) { return fill(i); })
                            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                            })
                            .text(function (d) { return d.text; });
                    $(target).append('hhh');
                }
                cloud(positions()[j].tags(), "#positionTagCloud" + positions()[j].id());
            };
        };

         //#endregion

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,
            cancel: cancel,
            toggleProfileUpload: toggleProfileUpload,

            title: 'Summary'
        };

        return vm;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with promises, then you need to register callback function using promise done method, so when promise will resolve, your UI will get updated.

```
promiseObject.done(function(){ 
    // Do something...
});
```

You can read documentation on jquery website: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Also, here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/3ugQp/

Comment: Tomas, thank you so much - is there any resources you could recommend where I could learn more about promises?

Comment: @TomasKirda - thanks for helping. You did indeed identify the problem and we all thank you. However, you overlooked one very important point: **Breeze uses Q.js promises, not jQuery promises**. They are different and the verbs, while often similar, are not always the same. Go to [**the Q.js web site**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#readme) to learn about Q and about promises in general.  If I may digress and editorialize for a moment, jQuery promises are flawed and do not follow the common.js Promises specification; avoid them. Use Q.js; use Q.when() to convert from jQuery promise as needed.

Comment: Thanks I 'promise' I will ;-)